# Can 'customer' column be easily changed to 'company name' in reports?

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a hook that I can use to change the **customer** column heading to the **company name**?

[image: Woocommerce admin screen]

Comment: "WooCommerce Admin" is JS based so it comes with no PHP hooks unfortunately. You'd need JS skills in order to override that column, and even then, you'd need even more to retrieve values. Anything is possible in WooCommerce, but in this case I'd find an alternative i.e. build my own reports in PHP

Comment: Thanks for the reply bb, unfortunate. I just searched through the core and yeah I see the js file... urgh

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments there are no hooks you can use here as the Analytics pages are rendered via JavaScript.

The code snippet below will add a mutation observer checking if the table on the order analytics page is changing (as these headers are being added dynamically via JavaScript). Each time a change (mutation) is registered it checks for the 'Customer' header. If it is found it is changed to 'Company name'. Perhaps not the most elegant solution but it does work.

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'woocommerce_analytics_change_customer_header' );
function woocommerce_analytics_change_customer_header() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) && isset( $_GET['path'] ) ) {
        if ( $_GET['page'] == 'wc-admin' && $_GET['path'] == '/analytics/orders' ) {
            ?>
            <script>
                jQuery( function( $ ) {

                    // select the target node
                    var target = document.querySelector('#woocommerce-layout__primary');

                    // create an observer instance
                    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                            if ( $('th.woocommerce-table__header').length ) {
                                $('th.woocommerce-table__header').each(function(){
                                    let $label = $(this).find('span');
                                    if ( $label.text() == 'Customer' ) {
                                        $label.text('Company name');
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    // configuration of the observer:
                    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };

                    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
                    observer.observe(target, config);

                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

This code snippet should be added to the functions.php of your child theme or via a plugin like Code Snippets.

Comment: Thanks TB, this does indeed changed the header, thanks for taking the time to whip this up!

Apologies maybe I should have mentioned that the fields below 'company name' should pull in the 'company name' data as well.